# Failed to write cookie using c#

Tags: c#, cookies, safari, visual-studio-2022

simple cookie setting like below ,on vs2017 all cases work good on chrome/edge/firefox/safari ;on vs2022 case 3 & 4 failed on safari.Is there anyone knows how to fix it ?

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //case 1
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("test1", "11111"));
            //case 2
            Response.Cookies["test2"].Value = "22222";
            //case 3
            setCookie1("test3", "33333");
            //case 4
            setCookie2("test4", "44444");
        }

        protected void setCookie1(string _name, string _value)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(_name, _value));
        }

        protected void setCookie2(string _name, string _value)
        {
            Response.Cookies[_name].Value = _value;
        }
```

*It can works by AddHeader "set-cookie", just trying to find other way.